# Databinding to nested UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I would like to bind a property from a nested UserControl to my MainWindow.
I'm already using a similar structure for other things but this is a bit different:

1. -MainWindow
2. --Ribbon
3. ---RibbonButton <-- the button I would like to disable
4. --/Ribbon
5. --UserControl1 - **not** directly the control I want bind to
6. ---UserControl2 - nested user control, sitting inside the above one
7. ----TextBox <-- Bind the RibbonButton to the Text property. Disable the button when TextBox empty
8. ---/UserControl2
9. --/UserControl
10. -/MainWindow

So, the usual combination of Elementname and Path doesn't work here obviously. Is DataContext the way to go here? The UserControls are in separate files and so is the MainWindow. Or should I do this in code-behind?

Some of the code I'm having there:

MainWindow

```
<RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</RibbonWindow.Resources>
...
            <RibbonGroup Header="Import">
                <RibbonButton x:Name="mplImpFromForum" Label="From forum" FontSize="12" LargeImageSource="Icons/General/Icon8_download_72px.png" Click="mplImpFromForum_Click"/>
                <RibbonButton x:Name="mplImpManual" Label="Manual import" SmallImageSource="Icons/General/Icon8_whole_hand_32px.png"}>
                    <RibbonButton.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=frmLogin, Path=}"
// here lies my problem
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RibbonButton.Style>
                </RibbonButton>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>

    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="200">
        <local:frmLogin x:Name="frmLogin" Loaded="frmLogin_Loaded" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <local:frmMPLMain x:Name="frmMPLMain" Grid.Row="1"/> // "Source UserControl, "parent 
to the real target.
```

The first nested UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Fever_Tool_WPF.frmMPLMain"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fever_Tool_WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="MPLRoot"
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1000">
...
    <local:frmMPLImp x:Name="frmMPLImp" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="6"/>
// The second UserControl, this one contains the TextBox I want to take as a source
    <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The second UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Fever_Tool_WPF.frmMPLImp"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fever_Tool_WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1000">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="uiMPLImpBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
    <TextBox x:Name="txtMPLImport" Style="{StaticResource uiMPLImpBaseStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
// This is the textbox I would like to check.
...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Two options: 1) UserControls share the parent's DataContext. Any child user control can bind to a property (say, `ImportText`) on the viewmodel, and any other user control with the same DataContext can bind to `ImportText` too. 2) If `frmMPLImp` is meant to be used in many different views with different viewmodels, it could expose the Text from that TextBox as a DependencyProperty and other controls could bind to it with ElementName bindings, or other viewmodels could have their properties bound to it in other views.